# How to use a variable defined inside a method use outside the method in another method on the same Class in java

Tags: java, android, oop

I am working on a android app , which connects to a omegle server, received message from a stranger , for that there is a complete API , there is a method send(message) which sends message to the server , but it can be used as session.send(mesage), because session is the variable which holds the omeglesession values, now here is my code -->

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.com.omegle.test;

import org.nikki.omegle.Omegle;
import org.nikki.omegle.core.OmegleException;
import org.nikki.omegle.core.OmegleMode;
import org.nikki.omegle.core.OmegleSession;
import org.nikki.omegle.event.OmegleEventAdaptor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView txt;
    Button m_btn;
    EditText m_edt;
    OmegleSession session;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        m_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        m_edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.type);
        m_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                sendIt(v);

            }
        });
        m_btn.setClickable(false);
        OmegleChat om=new OmegleChat();
        om.execute();
    }



    protected void sendIt(View v) 
    {

        txt.append("You: "+m_edt.getText().toString());
        m_edt.setText("");

        try {
            this.session.send(m_edt.getText().toString());
        } catch (OmegleException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }





    private class OmegleChat extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.omegle);
            txt.append("Omegele Connection Started... \n");

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        }
        @Override

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            OmgeleChatOn();
            return null;
        }

         @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


         }
  }

    public void OmgeleChatOn()
    {

        Omegle omegle = new Omegle();

        try {

            System.out.println("Opening session...");

            this.session = omegle.openSession(OmegleMode.NORMAL, new OmegleEventAdaptor() {

                @Override
                public void chatWaiting(OmegleSession session) {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for chat...");
                }


                @Override
                public void chatConnected(OmegleSession session) {
                    System.out.println("You are now talking to a random stranger!");
                }

                @Override
                public void chatMessage(final OmegleSession session, final String message) {
                    System.out.println("Stranger: " + message);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            txt.append("Stranger:"+message+"\n");
                            m_btn.setClickable(true);

                        }

                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void messageSent(OmegleSession session, final String string) {
                    System.out.println("You: " + string);
                  }

                @Override
                public void strangerDisconnected(OmegleSession session) {
                    System.out.println("Stranger disconnected, goodbye!");
                    //System.exit(0);
                }

                @Override
                public void omegleError(OmegleSession session, String string) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR! " + string);
                    System.exit(1);
                }



            });

            //HERE I WANT TO USE session.send(msg_from_edit_text) HOW TO DO THAT AS I HAVE A FUNCTION sendIt(v) above this method
            session.send("hi",true);


        } catch (OmegleException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }




}
```

now at line 156 above catch you can see a session.send("hi",true); it sends a message to server whenever i connect to server, but i want to use this in Sendit(v) method which is invoked when user presses a button from screen, So that it can send a user defined mesage to the server , but i cant do that , as session variable is defined in OmgeleChatOn function, and i cant use it outside that method, how to do this , i tried to search a lot but dint found the correct answer , please help ?

Comment: You can create object of your main class and use the method from it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply , can you explain a little , how can i access session object by the object of my main class ?

Comment: Make `OmegleSession session;` as static and then you can use it like: `MainActivity.session`. Make sure your session object is initialized before it is used.

Comment: @shree202  NEVER expose an Activity variable outside an Activity, especially static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found the solution of the problem myself , i tried using the session.send inside the mainActivity class and inside onclick. it worked like a charm.
here is the code -->

```
m_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        m_edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.type);
        m_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                session.send(m_edt.getText().toString());
                m_edt.setText("");

            } catch (OmegleException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
        });
```

and now the code works smooth

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a `hi` message after the connection is established, you should put the line in the `chatConnected()` callback method instead. The reason is, that you might otherwise try to send a message even if you are not connected. I don't know the Omegle API, but I assume that's the reason why you have callback methods in `OmegleEventAdaptor`.

Furthermore, if you want to send messages outside this callback class, you should assign the session to an instance field of `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public void chatConnected(OmegleSession session) {
  System.out.println("You are now talking to a random stranger!");
  session.send("hi", true);
  MainActivity.this.session = session;
}
```

Then you can simply access the session object from your `MainActivity`, e.g. if a button is clicked.

Comment: THANK YOU so much for your answer but i found that using session in onClick() method in the mainactivity class also solves my problem. and the problem is solved.